# IP usage in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I have an aks cluster with a single nodepool with azure cni network plugin and a subnet of /21 around 2000 ip's dedicated for this single nodepool. This nodepool is configured with 3 availability zones.

Consider I have another cluster with a single nodepool with the configuration same as above but for the nodepool availability zone is set to none.

Workloads are the same in both the nodepools. but will the nodepool deployed in 3 availability zones consume more ip's compared to the one deployed in the availability zone set to None

Answer (score 0):

AZ is for high Availability separated by a physical boundary within the region, Yes, It will consume separate IP's for each Node Pool. Selecting more than one availability zone will create same number of node pool and Consume same number of IP's.
I have tested in my environment with 3 AZ it occupied my 3 Ip's address from the selected subnet.

Comment: So as you said will the ip's consumed and number of nodes for the application running in nodepool with 3 az's and 1az's will be same. Only the availabbility factor will be different right @RahulKumarShaw

Comment: No , number of ip's will be different for 3az and 1az. 3az will create 3 nodepool so it consume 3 ip's and 1az will create 1 nodepool and consume 1 ip's